# Construction of Angular Momentum eigenvectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space

I have a problem that asks (verbatim)

> Carryout the construction of the eigenvectors of total angular momentum and its z component for $j_1$=3/2 and $j_2$=1/2

I am not completely sure where to start out with this.  Our professor has not given the best explanation.  The equations I have been trying to use are the following:

$$\textbf{L}^2|l,m\rangle =\hbar^2l(l+1)|l,m\rangle$$
$$\textbf{L}_z|l,m\rangle=\hbar m|l,m\rangle$$

I figure I probably want to use the same equations, but for $\bf J$ instead of $\bf L$.  I am also confused what the differences between $j_1$ and $j_2$ would represent.  I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: I am not sure.  I would guess a free particle.

Comment: Some form of system with adding angular momenta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna guess the problem involves the angular momentum states with $\ell=1$ and the spin-1/2 states.  I'm making this guess because, when $j$ is half-integer, there is no "stand-alone" representation of the states in terms of regular (spherical or otherwise) coordinates, i.e. there is nothing like the spherical harmonics $Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi)$ which depend on the physical polar and azimuthal angles $\theta$ and $\phi$.  Moreover, in putting together the states of $\ell=1$ and $s=1/2$, one *does* obtain $j=1/2$ and $j=3/2$.

There are two ways to proceed.  The first is the "cheap" way which is to use pre-tabulated Clesbch-Gordan coefficients.  Thus, in general
$$
\vert j m\rangle = \sum_{\alpha\beta}
\vert 1;\alpha\rangle \vert \textstyle \frac{1}{2} ;\beta\rangle 
C^{jm}_{1\alpha;\frac{1}{2}\beta}\, ,\qquad 
\alpha \in \{1,0,-1\}\, ,\quad \beta\in\{\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\}
$$
where $C^{jm}_{1\alpha;\frac{1}{2}\beta}$ is a Clebsch-Gordan coefficient, with $j=1/2$ or $3/2$.
It's just a matter of looking up the appropriate coefficient.

A more explicitly way is to start with 
$$
\vert 11\rangle \vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle
$$
and note that this state is killed by 
$L_+=L^{(1)}_++L^{(2)}_+$ where $L^{(1)}_+$ acts on the first factor alone, and $L^{(2)}_+$ acts on the second factor alone, i.e.
$$
L^{(1)}_+\vert 1\alpha\rangle \vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\beta\rangle = \sqrt{(1-\alpha)(1+\alpha+1)}
\vert 1,\alpha+1\rangle \vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\beta\rangle 
$$
etc.  Thus, one easily verifies that
\begin{align}
L_+\vert 11\rangle \vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle&=0\,  ,\\
L_z\vert 11\rangle \vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle&=\textstyle\frac{3}{2}
\vert 11\rangle \vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle\, .
\end{align}
Since the *only* way to kill an angular momentum state is when its $L_z$-eigenvalue is equal to $j$, this identifies 
$$
\vert \textstyle\frac{3}{2}\frac{3}{2}\rangle 
= \vert 11\rangle \vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle\, .
$$
To get the other states in the sequence, use the lowering operator $L_-$.  For instance
$$
L_-\vert \textstyle\frac{3}{2}\frac{3}{2}\rangle 
=\sqrt{3}\vert \textstyle\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle
=\sqrt{2}\vert 10\rangle\vert \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle+\vert 11\rangle \vert \frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle  
$$
and thus
$$
\vert \textstyle\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle
=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\vert 10\rangle\vert \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\vert 11\rangle \vert \frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle  \, . \tag{1}
$$
One then notes there are two possible eigenstates of $L_z$ with eigenvalue $1/2$.  They are $\sqrt{2}\vert 10\rangle\vert \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ and $\vert 11\rangle \vert \frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$.  Clearly, (1) is a linear combination of these two. Consider now the combination orthogonal to (1):
$$
\vert\chi\rangle=\sqrt{\textstyle\frac{1}{3}}\vert 10\rangle\vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\vert 11\rangle \vert \frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle  \, . \tag{2}
$$ 
One readily verifies that
$$
L_+\vert\chi\rangle= 
\sqrt{\textstyle\frac{2}{3}}\vert 11\rangle\vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\vert 11\rangle \vert \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle=0 \tag{3}
$$
which makes $\vert\chi\rangle$ the $\vert\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ since it is killed by $L_+$ and has $L_z$-eigenvalue $1/2$.

We can use the lowering operator $L_-$ on (1) to obtain the $\vert \frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ state and likewise on (3) to obtain the $\vert\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ states, and finally complete the calculation by using $L_-$ on $\vert \frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do solve this, you can do it using the theory of  Clebsch-Gordon coefficients. This are sets of numbers that arise in angular momentum coupling under the laws of quantum mechanics. So you only need to find out a table with this coefficients for $j_{1} =3/2$ and $j_{2} =1/2$. The theory can be found in this link http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/lectures/node47.html, and the table of the coefficients in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients